# How to authenticate using username/password/domain via ManagementScope

Tags: c#, .net, authentication

Have a utility I wrote that checks (among other things) the last time a set of servers was rebooted.  This works great as long as the servers are all within my domain and the user launching the app have rights on the servers. Added a section where the user can specify alternative credentials, in our case specifically to deal with another domain.  The credentials I am feeding into have domain admin rights on the destination domain, yet my code is getting an Access Denied (Unauthorized Access) error.

thanks!

```
private void btnLastReboot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConnectionOptions conOpts = new ConnectionOptions();

        if (selectedList.Count > 0)
        {
            Cursor currentCursor = Cursor.Current;
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

            stripProgress.Visible = true;
            stripProgress.Minimum = 0;
            stripProgress.Maximum = selectedList.Count();
            stripProgress.Step = 1;
            stripProgress.Value = 0;

            rtfOut.SelectionTabs = new int[] { 100, 200 };
            rtfOut.Text = "";

            var sq = new SelectQuery("Win32_OperatingSystem");

            if (prefs.useCurrentUser == true)
            {
                // Setting all fields to NULL causes current user info to be used
                conOpts.Username = null;
                conOpts.Password = null;
                conOpts.Authority = null;
            }
            else
            {
                conOpts.Username = prefs.userName;
                conOpts.Password = prefs.password.ToString();
                conOpts.Authority = "ntlmdomain:" + prefs.domain;

            }

            foreach (ServerList anEntry in selectedList)
            {
                stripProgress.Value++;

                try
                {
                    var mgmtScope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + anEntry.ServerName + "\\root\\cimv2", conOpts);
                    mgmtScope.Connect();
                    var mgmtSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(mgmtScope, sq);
                    foreach (var item in mgmtSearcher.Get())
                    {
                        var lastBoot = item.GetPropertyValue("LastBootUpTime").ToString();
                        DateTime lboot = ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(lastBoot);
                        rtfOut.Text += anEntry.ServerName + "\t";
                        if(anEntry.ServerName.Length <= 9)
                        {
                            rtfOut.Text += "\t";
                        }
                        rtfOut.Text += lboot.ToLongDateString() + " (" + lboot.ToLongTimeString() + ")\r\n";
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (ex is UnauthorizedAccessException)
                    {
                        rtfOut.Text += anEntry.ServerName + "\t <Access Denied>\r\n";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rtfOut.Text += anEntry.ServerName + "\t <not responding>\r\n";
                    }
                }
            }

            stripProgress.Visible = false;
            Cursor.Current = currentCursor;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add to the ConnectionOption: `conOpts.EnablePrivileges = true; conOpts.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy; conOpts.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;`. Also, see the WMI Management.Infrastructure method: [Connecting to WMI Remotely with C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/connecting-to-wmi-remotely-with-c-).

Answer (score 1):

Had to sleep on it, but the answer finally hit me in the shower...

I store the password the user provides in a SecureString variable, but the ConnectionOptions' password field expects the value as a clear string.  I was able to test this by temporarily hard coding a password in, which then worked.  The final solution was to convert the SecureString to a clear string and then assign it to the ConnectionOption.

If anyone is curious, I used this bit to convert the password back:

```
string password = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(string.Empty, securePassword).Password;
```